# Clicking one of SVG parts to show an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

I'm a JS noob, never touched any coding other than simple CSS stuff.
What I'm trying to do here is to create an interactive graphic where you click a part of the SVG, and it shows you a picture. I'm going for the image to show within the SVG itself somewhere at the bottom.
Here's the code I used:

```
 <script>
function myFunction(idblue) {
    var bluepic = "https://i.ibb.co/yfn8GwC/bluecity.jpg";
    document.getElementById(idblue).src = bluepic;
}
```

and I put the `onclick` on `<path>` like this.

```
<path id="bluecity" onclick="myFunction('idblue')" class="bc" d="000 000 000..."> </path>
```

And to display the picture at the bottom, I used this line before, but right now it isn't in the SVG file I linked down there.

```
 <img class="pic" id="idblue" x="10" y="200"> </img>
```

However, the picture doesn't appear when you click on the corresponding part (so far, I only managed to show text with similar lines). Here's also the [SVG file](https://filebin.net/sit21ua2j0c0og7d) I'm fiddling with. How do I make it work?

Comment: Where is the value of idblue being set? or what value are you trying to make it be? Does a html element somewhere on the page have an id="idblue"

Comment: When you say "it shows you a picture" -- do you mean that the picture should be shown within the SVG itself, or somewhere on a web page in which the SVG is included? Could you draw a diagram of what you want on paper and add that to your question?

Comment: @Wayne I wasn't really sure since this is the first time I did something with JS, and no, I didn't set idblue to any value. I thought idblue would serve as a "tag" to myFunction so onclick can trigger the correct script.

Comment: @BrettDonald I meant within the SVG itself. I also added more information to my question about it. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @topography does serve as a tag but being that function myFunction(idblue) is the same name ... it looks confused. I'd function myFunctionn(elementID) and document.getElementById(elementID).src = ... then when read it we know that onclick="myFunction('idblue')" is as intended. One could also call myFunction with a variable onclick = "myFunction(idblue)"; ... but if doing that then for readability use javascript to set the event so people don't need to go from one page HTML file then to another page javascript file and back.

Answer (score 0):

just add the script to the html of the site instead of inside the svg and it should work fine.

```js
function myFunction(idblue) {
    var bluepic = "https://i.ibb.co/yfn8GwC/bluecity.jpg";
    document.getElementById(idblue).src = bluepic;
}
```

```html
<img id = "idblue">
<svg
   viewBox="0 0 400 400"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.1.2 (b8e25be833, 2022-02-05)"
   sodipodi:docname="colourfultest.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.49798681"
     inkscape:cx="307.23705"
     inkscape:cy="562.26389"
     inkscape:window-width="1300"
     inkscape:window-height="745"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg5" />
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
    
 <style type="text/css">
    .land {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
        stroke-miterlimit: 4;
    }
    .circle {
        opacity: 0;
        fill-opacity: 1;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 0.5;
        stroke-opacity: 1;
    }
    path:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
 </style>
 
  <path id="bluecity" onclick="myFunction('idblue')" class="bc"
     style="display:inline;fill:#008080;stroke-width:0.531307"
     d="m 88.728086,215.13469 c -4.383275,-0.85084 -8.447765,-1.76804 -9.0322,-2.03822 -0.584438,-0.27018 -3.45349,-0.6237 -6.375673,-0.78561 -2.922182,-0.1619 -6.180121,-0.54227 -7.239868,-0.84526 -2.218883,-0.63439 -4.714515,-2.90179 -4.714515,-4.28336 0,-2.25724 3.359785,-9.6287 5.317104,-11.66588 1.116415,-1.16196 2.110166,-2.31789 2.208339,-2.56873 0.09817,-0.25084 1.194615,-1.09253 2.436543,-1.87041 1.241928,-0.77789 2.258052,-1.61225 2.258052,-1.85413 0,-0.24188 1.29462,-0.75036 2.876934,-1.12995 2.699123,-0.64751 2.898968,-0.8076 3.233385,-2.5902 0.622493,-3.31818 3.923255,-8.57808 5.383028,-8.57808 0.779145,0 2.92205,-1.0698 3.394831,-1.6948 0.152498,-0.20159 1.179237,-0.97863 2.281645,-1.72674 2.574552,-1.74714 5.27671,-1.79093 7.265191,-0.11773 1.982278,1.66798 7.247568,3.73676 12.773188,5.01871 2.4931,0.5784 5.41484,1.65014 6.49277,2.38164 1.07792,0.7315 4.22992,2.20957 7.00442,3.28461 5.88597,2.28062 7.23529,3.58417 8.73457,8.43828 2.35765,7.63317 1.90294,14.0327 -1.21889,17.15453 -3.3572,3.3572 -19.31992,7.15173 -29.71618,7.06388 -3.610701,-0.0305 -8.026991,-0.55684 -13.362674,-1.59255 z">
    </path>
     
  <path id="redcity" class="rc"
     style="fill:#ff5555;stroke-width:0.531307"
     d="m 109.27514,170.51745 c -1.97083,-0.79008 -5.92979,-4.25918 -6.81572,-5.97239 -0.44664,-0.8637 -1.17199,-2.79492 -1.61189,-4.29161 -0.43991,-1.49669 -1.164654,-3.13127 -1.610554,-3.63242 -0.470961,-0.52931 -0.690076,-1.41996 -0.522835,-2.12522 0.50968,-2.14937 1.772199,-5.21524 2.410439,-5.85349 0.34127,-0.34127 0.6205,-1.33274 0.6205,-2.20326 0,-0.87051 0.22535,-2.317 0.50079,-3.2144 1.05212,-3.42798 3.21957,-13.38571 3.21897,-14.78867 -2.6e-4,-0.80756 -0.20453,-1.88346 -0.45375,-2.39088 -1.27324,-2.59233 -2.14883,-4.7966 -2.45307,-6.1756 -0.2965,-1.34389 -1.80374,-3.24177 -5.902118,-7.43183 -0.607412,-0.621 -2.123361,-1.9659 -3.368775,-2.98867 -1.760128,-1.44545 -2.916987,-3.22023 -5.194845,-7.96958 -3.506531,-7.311156 -4.277569,-9.934897 -4.677789,-15.917893 -0.166933,-2.495564 -0.417975,-5.438532 -0.557871,-6.539931 -0.221242,-1.741827 -0.08786,-2.065846 1.024527,-2.488774 0.832139,-0.316379 1.603682,-1.336707 2.208684,-2.920879 0.672184,-1.760087 1.296437,-2.526667 2.253091,-2.766771 1.463543,-0.367327 7.541728,0.803132 14.441796,2.781011 2.47123,0.708367 5.12391,1.287939 5.89485,1.287939 0.77094,0 1.83537,0.479184 2.36539,1.064853 0.53002,0.585668 1.89322,1.315151 3.02933,1.621075 3.23801,0.871906 9.94498,7.943713 14.76739,15.570682 2.19164,3.466226 6.13658,9.084788 8.76655,12.485688 l 4.78175,6.18346 -0.0756,9.29785 c -0.0416,5.11382 -0.33196,10.37375 -0.64529,11.68874 -0.31332,1.31498 -1.15339,5.0543 -1.86681,8.3096 -1.50649,6.87401 -1.21612,6.25738 -7.16195,15.20945 -2.52759,3.80554 -5.07378,7.68691 -5.65822,8.62527 -1.73758,2.78983 -2.46275,3.47169 -5.1292,4.82288 -2.10389,1.06613 -3.29418,1.28104 -6.94035,1.25314 -2.42051,-0.0186 -4.95735,-0.25674 -5.63742,-0.52937 z">
    </path>
     
  <path id="peachcity" class="pc"
     style="fill:#ff9955;stroke-width:0.531307"
     d="m 61.027386,182.81041 c -4.252931,-1.93119 -7.431894,-5.68353 -12.498004,-14.75221 -1.682308,-3.01144 -8.242038,-10.56109 -13.157422,-15.14299 -8.732758,-8.1403 -13.004832,-17.1289 -11.241577,-23.65271 0.784462,-2.90241 3.581932,-6.5536 5.908882,-7.71213 1.011499,-0.5036 3.968387,-1.93591 6.570863,-3.18292 6.035233,-2.89184 9.347832,-5.96046 9.347832,-8.65935 0,-3.06735 -1.278133,-4.80954 -5.215464,-7.10906 -6.313357,-3.687203 -9.805995,-8.536949 -10.519391,-14.606842 -0.324919,-2.764555 -0.319691,-2.776802 2.889012,-6.765449 4.200583,-5.221629 5.819957,-6.308159 15.6352,-10.490547 1.388036,-0.591457 2.523702,-1.357995 2.523702,-1.703416 0,-1.008605 11.313345,-0.328869 14.876565,0.893826 2.338245,0.802351 2.958568,1.260366 3.104264,2.292027 0.100142,0.709115 0.544504,1.842431 0.98747,2.518481 0.65306,0.996699 0.73465,2.21755 0.431371,6.454828 -0.337135,4.710301 -0.264229,5.430491 0.739272,7.302807 0.612312,1.142442 1.113295,2.442528 1.113295,2.889083 0,1.278618 3.55858,6.33816 6.913788,9.829932 3.918794,4.0783 5.241695,6.26134 7.739528,12.77168 l 2.030666,5.29272 0.206084,11.42308 c 0.251312,13.93002 -0.251579,18.67761 -3.067224,28.95617 -3.987387,14.55602 -7.51255,19.72735 -15.413141,22.61071 -4.972677,1.81481 -6.873973,1.91889 -9.905571,0.54228 z">
    </path>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to show different images on the `<img>` tag depending on the part of the SVG you click. In the snippet below, I've only used a single `<img>` tag that changes sources between clicks. I have put the styles for the SVG on the `<head>` tag, which is where they should be most of the times (there are rare exceptions). I've also refactored your code to use .addEventListener(), which is vastly preferred over the HTML onclick="".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>How to make a PIN</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .land {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
        stroke-miterlimit: 4;
      }

      .circle {
        opacity: 0;
        fill-opacity: 1;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 0.5;
        stroke-opacity: 1;
      }

      path:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" version="1.1" id="svg5" inkscape:version="1.1.2 (b8e25be833, 2022-02-05)" sodipodi:docname="colourfultest.svg" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <sodipodi:namedview id="namedview7" pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:pageopacity="0.0" inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0" inkscape:document-units="mm" showgrid="false" inkscape:zoom="0.49798681" inkscape:cx="307.23705" inkscape:cy="562.26389" inkscape:window-width="1300" inkscape:window-height="745" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:current-layer="svg5" />
        <defs id="defs2" />
        <path id="bluecity" class="bc" style="display:inline;fill:#008080;stroke-width:0.531307" d="m 88.728086,215.13469 c -4.383275,-0.85084 -8.447765,-1.76804 -9.0322,-2.03822 -0.584438,-0.27018 -3.45349,-0.6237 -6.375673,-0.78561 -2.922182,-0.1619 -6.180121,-0.54227 -7.239868,-0.84526 -2.218883,-0.63439 -4.714515,-2.90179 -4.714515,-4.28336 0,-2.25724 3.359785,-9.6287 5.317104,-11.66588 1.116415,-1.16196 2.110166,-2.31789 2.208339,-2.56873 0.09817,-0.25084 1.194615,-1.09253 2.436543,-1.87041 1.241928,-0.77789 2.258052,-1.61225 2.258052,-1.85413 0,-0.24188 1.29462,-0.75036 2.876934,-1.12995 2.699123,-0.64751 2.898968,-0.8076 3.233385,-2.5902 0.622493,-3.31818 3.923255,-8.57808 5.383028,-8.57808 0.779145,0 2.92205,-1.0698 3.394831,-1.6948 0.152498,-0.20159 1.179237,-0.97863 2.281645,-1.72674 2.574552,-1.74714 5.27671,-1.79093 7.265191,-0.11773 1.982278,1.66798 7.247568,3.73676 12.773188,5.01871 2.4931,0.5784 5.41484,1.65014 6.49277,2.38164 1.07792,0.7315 4.22992,2.20957 7.00442,3.28461 5.88597,2.28062 7.23529,3.58417 8.73457,8.43828 2.35765,7.63317 1.90294,14.0327 -1.21889,17.15453 -3.3572,3.3572 -19.31992,7.15173 -29.71618,7.06388 -3.610701,-0.0305 -8.026991,-0.55684 -13.362674,-1.59255 z"></path>
        <path id="redcity" class="rc" style="fill:#ff5555;stroke-width:0.531307" d="m 109.27514,170.51745 c -1.97083,-0.79008 -5.92979,-4.25918 -6.81572,-5.97239 -0.44664,-0.8637 -1.17199,-2.79492 -1.61189,-4.29161 -0.43991,-1.49669 -1.164654,-3.13127 -1.610554,-3.63242 -0.470961,-0.52931 -0.690076,-1.41996 -0.522835,-2.12522 0.50968,-2.14937 1.772199,-5.21524 2.410439,-5.85349 0.34127,-0.34127 0.6205,-1.33274 0.6205,-2.20326 0,-0.87051 0.22535,-2.317 0.50079,-3.2144 1.05212,-3.42798 3.21957,-13.38571 3.21897,-14.78867 -2.6e-4,-0.80756 -0.20453,-1.88346 -0.45375,-2.39088 -1.27324,-2.59233 -2.14883,-4.7966 -2.45307,-6.1756 -0.2965,-1.34389 -1.80374,-3.24177 -5.902118,-7.43183 -0.607412,-0.621 -2.123361,-1.9659 -3.368775,-2.98867 -1.760128,-1.44545 -2.916987,-3.22023 -5.194845,-7.96958 -3.506531,-7.311156 -4.277569,-9.934897 -4.677789,-15.917893 -0.166933,-2.495564 -0.417975,-5.438532 -0.557871,-6.539931 -0.221242,-1.741827 -0.08786,-2.065846 1.024527,-2.488774 0.832139,-0.316379 1.603682,-1.336707 2.208684,-2.920879 0.672184,-1.760087 1.296437,-2.526667 2.253091,-2.766771 1.463543,-0.367327 7.541728,0.803132 14.441796,2.781011 2.47123,0.708367 5.12391,1.287939 5.89485,1.287939 0.77094,0 1.83537,0.479184 2.36539,1.064853 0.53002,0.585668 1.89322,1.315151 3.02933,1.621075 3.23801,0.871906 9.94498,7.943713 14.76739,15.570682 2.19164,3.466226 6.13658,9.084788 8.76655,12.485688 l 4.78175,6.18346 -0.0756,9.29785 c -0.0416,5.11382 -0.33196,10.37375 -0.64529,11.68874 -0.31332,1.31498 -1.15339,5.0543 -1.86681,8.3096 -1.50649,6.87401 -1.21612,6.25738 -7.16195,15.20945 -2.52759,3.80554 -5.07378,7.68691 -5.65822,8.62527 -1.73758,2.78983 -2.46275,3.47169 -5.1292,4.82288 -2.10389,1.06613 -3.29418,1.28104 -6.94035,1.25314 -2.42051,-0.0186 -4.95735,-0.25674 -5.63742,-0.52937 z"></path>
        <path id="peachcity" class="pc" style="fill:#ff9955;stroke-width:0.531307" d="m 61.027386,182.81041 c -4.252931,-1.93119 -7.431894,-5.68353 -12.498004,-14.75221 -1.682308,-3.01144 -8.242038,-10.56109 -13.157422,-15.14299 -8.732758,-8.1403 -13.004832,-17.1289 -11.241577,-23.65271 0.784462,-2.90241 3.581932,-6.5536 5.908882,-7.71213 1.011499,-0.5036 3.968387,-1.93591 6.570863,-3.18292 6.035233,-2.89184 9.347832,-5.96046 9.347832,-8.65935 0,-3.06735 -1.278133,-4.80954 -5.215464,-7.10906 -6.313357,-3.687203 -9.805995,-8.536949 -10.519391,-14.606842 -0.324919,-2.764555 -0.319691,-2.776802 2.889012,-6.765449 4.200583,-5.221629 5.819957,-6.308159 15.6352,-10.490547 1.388036,-0.591457 2.523702,-1.357995 2.523702,-1.703416 0,-1.008605 11.313345,-0.328869 14.876565,0.893826 2.338245,0.802351 2.958568,1.260366 3.104264,2.292027 0.100142,0.709115 0.544504,1.842431 0.98747,2.518481 0.65306,0.996699 0.73465,2.21755 0.431371,6.454828 -0.337135,4.710301 -0.264229,5.430491 0.739272,7.302807 0.612312,1.142442 1.113295,2.442528 1.113295,2.889083 0,1.278618 3.55858,6.33816 6.913788,9.829932 3.918794,4.0783 5.241695,6.26134 7.739528,12.77168 l 2.030666,5.29272 0.206084,11.42308 c 0.251312,13.93002 -0.251579,18.67761 -3.067224,28.95617 -3.987387,14.55602 -7.51255,19.72735 -15.413141,22.61071 -4.972677,1.81481 -6.873973,1.91889 -9.905571,0.54228 z"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="images-container">
      <img id="image_tag" src="" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("bluecity").addEventListener("click", showImage);
            document.getElementById("redcity").addEventListener("click", showImage);
            document.getElementById("peachcity").addEventListener("click", showImage);
        }
    
      function showImage() {
        const imageSource = getImageSourceFromPath(this);
        const imageElement = document.getElementById("image_tag");
        
        imageElement.src = imageSource;
        imageElement.style.display = "block";
      }

      function getImageSourceFromPath(path) {
        switch (path.id) {
          case "bluecity":
            return "https://i.ibb.co/yfn8GwC/bluecity.jpg";
          case "redcity":
            return "https://i.ibb.co/yfn8GwC/redcity.jpg";
          case "peachcity":
            return "https://i.ibb.co/yfn8GwC/peachcity.jpg";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this creating a more standalone svg:
svg would include an `<image>` element (not to be confused with html `<img>` tag) and your js script.

**image element**

```
  <image xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="60%" width="50%" height="33%" id="image" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAMAAAAoyzS7AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAAZQTFRF////AAAAVcLTfgAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAAMSURBVHjaYmAACDAAAAIAAU9tWeEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
```

Unlike html `<img>` tag  svg `<image>` takes a `href` attribute for referencing image files.
The above example has a transparent png (converted to a data URL) as a default.

**Example usage: standalone svg**

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" id="svg5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <style type="text/css">
          .land {
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 1.5;
            stroke-miterlimit: 4
          }
      
          .circle {
            opacity: 0;
            fill-opacity: 1;
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: .5;
            stroke-opacity: 1
          }
      
          path:hover {
            opacity: .5
          }
        </style>
        <path id="bluecity" data-img="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" class="city bc" style="fill:teal;stroke-width:.531307" d="M88.73 215.13c-4.39-.85-8.45-1.76-9.03-2.03-.59-.27-3.46-.63-6.38-.79a48.03 48.03 0 0 1-7.24-.84c-2.22-.64-4.71-2.9-4.71-4.29 0-2.25 3.36-9.63 5.31-11.66a19.58 19.58 0 0 0 2.21-2.57c.1-.25 1.2-1.1 2.44-1.87 1.24-.78 2.26-1.62 2.26-1.86s1.29-.75 2.87-1.13c2.7-.64 2.9-.8 3.24-2.59.62-3.32 3.92-8.58 5.38-8.58.78 0 2.92-1.06 3.4-1.69.15-.2 1.17-.98 2.28-1.73 2.57-1.74 5.27-1.79 7.26-.11 1.98 1.66 7.25 3.73 12.77 5.01 2.5.58 5.42 1.65 6.5 2.39 1.07.73 4.23 2.2 7 3.28 5.89 2.28 7.24 3.58 8.74 8.44 2.35 7.63 1.9 14.03-1.22 17.15-3.36 3.36-19.32 7.16-29.72 7.07a75.39 75.39 0 0 1-13.36-1.6z" />
        <path id="redcity"  data-img="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" class="city rc" style="fill:#f55;stroke-width:.531307" d="M109.28 170.52c-1.98-.8-5.93-4.26-6.82-5.97-.45-.87-1.17-2.8-1.61-4.3a12.66 12.66 0 0 0-1.61-3.63 2.54 2.54 0 0 1-.53-2.12c.51-2.15 1.78-5.22 2.41-5.86.35-.34.63-1.33.63-2.2 0-.87.22-2.32.5-3.22 1.05-3.42 3.22-13.38 3.21-14.78 0-.81-.2-1.89-.45-2.4a31.7 31.7 0 0 1-2.45-6.17c-.3-1.34-1.8-3.24-5.9-7.43a54.2 54.2 0 0 0-3.37-3c-1.76-1.44-2.92-3.21-5.2-7.96-3.5-7.31-4.28-9.94-4.68-15.92-.16-2.5-.41-5.44-.55-6.54-.22-1.74-.1-2.06 1.02-2.49.83-.31 1.6-1.33 2.21-2.92.67-1.76 1.3-2.52 2.25-2.76 1.47-.37 7.54.8 14.44 2.78 2.48.7 5.13 1.28 5.9 1.28.77 0 1.83.48 2.36 1.07a7.6 7.6 0 0 0 3.03 1.62c3.24.87 9.95 7.94 14.77 15.57 2.2 3.47 6.14 9.09 8.77 12.49l4.78 6.18-.08 9.3c-.04 5.11-.33 10.37-.64 11.69-.31 1.31-1.15 5.05-1.87 8.3-1.5 6.88-1.21 6.26-7.16 15.22-2.53 3.8-5.07 7.68-5.66 8.62-1.74 2.8-2.46 3.47-5.13 4.82-2.1 1.07-3.3 1.28-6.94 1.26-2.42-.02-4.95-.26-5.63-.53z" />
        <path id="peachcity"  data-img="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" class="city pc" style="fill:#f95;stroke-width:.531307" d="M61.03 182.81c-4.26-1.93-7.43-5.68-12.5-14.75-1.68-3.01-8.24-10.56-13.16-15.14-8.73-8.15-13-17.13-11.24-23.66.78-2.9 3.58-6.55 5.9-7.71 1.02-.5 3.98-1.94 6.58-3.18 6.04-2.9 9.35-5.96 9.35-8.66 0-3.07-1.28-4.81-5.22-7.11-6.31-3.69-9.8-8.54-10.52-14.6-.32-2.77-.32-2.78 2.9-6.77 4.2-5.22 5.81-6.31 15.63-10.5 1.39-.59 2.52-1.35 2.52-1.7 0-1 11.31-.33 14.88.9 2.34.8 2.96 1.26 3.1 2.29.1.7.55 1.84.99 2.52.65 1 .73 2.21.43 6.45-.34 4.71-.26 5.43.74 7.3a9.57 9.57 0 0 1 1.11 2.9c0 1.27 3.56 6.33 6.92 9.82 3.92 4.08 5.24 6.27 7.74 12.78l2.03 5.29.2 11.42c.25 13.93-.25 18.68-3.06 28.96-4 14.55-7.52 19.72-15.42 22.6-4.97 1.82-6.87 1.93-9.9.55z" />
      
      <image xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="60%" width="50%" height="33%" id="image" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAMAAAAoyzS7AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAAZQTFRF////AAAAVcLTfgAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAAMSURBVHjaYmAACDAAAAIAAU9tWeEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
      
        <script>
           const image = document.querySelector('#image');
           const cities = document.querySelectorAll('.city');
           cities.forEach(function(city){
              city.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                     let imgSrc = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-img');
                     image.setAttribute('href', imgSrc);
              })
           })
        </script>
      </svg>
```

Different images could be stored in data attributes like so:

```
 <path id="bluecity" data-img="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" class="city bc" />
```

This way we can use a generic image swap function for many shapes/cities

```
const image = document.querySelector('#image');
const cities = document.querySelectorAll('.city');
cities.forEach(function(city){
   city.addEventListener('click', function(e){
         let imgSrc = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-img');
         image.setAttribute('href', imgSrc);
   })
})
```

**Html**

You can add this svg to your html body using a `<object>` element:

```
 <object data="colourfultest.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="400" height="400"></object>
```